# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/flex-layout' in '/app'

Tags: angular, npm, node-modules, package.json, angular-flex-layout

I suddenly got this error

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/flex-layout' in '\src\app'
```

This error occurred After  I have install @angular/cdk,

After this error I have again installed flex-layout using

```
 npm install @angular/flex-layout
```

But now there is error for

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/http' in '\src\app'
```

If I Install a http, then some other module is getting missed. How to stop this situation? What has gone wrong?

If I install @angular/http then again it starts with

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/flex-layout' in '\src\app'
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try adding full read-write access to node_modules folder

```
chmod -R 777 /node_modules
```

Then update the node_modules package

```
npm install
```

Answer (score 7):

Install the below package to avoid this issue.

```
npm install @angular/flex-layout
```

**OR** add the below code in `package.json` and do the `npm install`

```
"@angular/flex-layout":"12.0.0-beta.34"
```

Answer (score 2):

if you are having problem as shown in image then it is require to run -

```
npm install @angular/flex-layout --force
```

this command forcefully install flex-layout to your machine.

Answer (score 1):

For me, the issue was with the @angular/cdk version.@angular/flex-layout required version 12.0.0 for installation. Simply go to package.json and change the @angular/cdk version to 12.0.0.
Then run `npm install -s @angular/flex-layout`

Answer (score 0):

Try to keep the same version of angular cdk and angular/flex-layout.
for me also having same issue due to layout version was higher than angular c